# When are TCM URIs "managed?"

Tags: content-porter

I remember news about TCM URIs being "managed" by Content Porter if they were in rich text format areas, meaning they could be properly mapped from one DTAP environment to another (using presumably WebDAV), but for more than just Component and Multimedia Component references, sometime around 2013.

1. Was this a public, supported feature? If so, when was it added?
2. Was the restriction only for rich text format areas? I thought TCM URIs might already be handled in template code even before this.
3. What types of items are managed (Page references, Templates, Keywords...)?
4. Does Import/Export API have the same feature?

Finally, any examples of this feature being used by the product itself or in implementations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. XLinks in custom content/metadata are "managed" by CM Kernel. Meaning: if such XLinks contains a TCM URI or WebDAV URL of a CM Component, a managed Component link will created (which shows up in Where Used and prevents the linked Component from being deleted). This also allows you to request the XLink as TCM URI or WebDAV URL (regardless of how it was saved). When exporting, WebDAV URLs are always requested to facilitate porting to different environments.  AFAIR, this has been the case since TCM 5.0.  CM Kernel allows XLinks to Components, Keywords and Categories (!) What you may be referring to is the ability of Content Porter to deal with unmanaged TCM URIs in App Data?
2. Indeed, template code can have managed links to any kind of (organizational) item.
3. See 1; Custom content/metadata can only contain Component, Keyword and Category links.
4. Content Porter is only a front-end for the CM Import/Export API (since 2013 SP1).

Comment: It might indeed have been TCM URIs in App Data. I think this was around the same time Content Porter started having the options to include App Data (which I can't remember if they appeared at the _same time_ as App Data or shortly after).

Comment: In terms of XLinks to Categories, I know we can select Categories in Schema definitions (for selections for a given text field). But could you choose/insert Category TCM URIs anywhere and have the CM Kernal manage them? I'm thinking of Bart's Item Selector extension, which stores TCM URIs as strings (and wouldn't be content portable), right?

Comment: Yeah, managed links to Categories in custom content/metadata are a weird beast; the UI doesn't support them, but the CM Kernel does allow them (AFAIR, we had some taxonomy publishing  use case in mind that was never actually implemented).  Indeed, storing TCM URIs in text fields does not result in managed links.